# How do I print .so file location at runtime?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

In foo.c

```
void location(char *path)
{
    //to do
}
```

In main.c

```
int main()
{
    char foopath[256];
    
    location(foopath);
    
    printf("%s\n",foopath);
}
```

Maybe it will show `/lib/foo.so`

I think I can use shell script such as ldd to get the path, but it seems not pretty.

I want to read a file at the same location as the `foo.so`. So I need the correct path.

Comment: This might be a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem So please take a logical step back and explain what you want to achieve by using this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "dl" library. Example of program which displays the name of the dynamic library file of the "fopen" symbol:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int rc;
  Dl_info info;

  rc = dladdr(fopen, &info);
  if (rc) {
    printf("%s\n", info.dli_fname);
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

$ gcc example.c -l dl
$ ./a.out
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```